# List which of the most competing members from each category got the highest score

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables:

User

```
create table user (
  id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  name varchar(30),
  soyad varchar(50),
  city varchar(30),
  e_mail varchar(100),
  pass varchar(10)
);
```

Category

```
create table category(
  id int not null primary key,
  name varchar(50)
);
```

Competition

```
create table competition(
  id int primary key,
  date date,
  category_id int foreign key references category(id)
);
```

Competition_User

```
create table competition_user(
  id int primary key,
  competition_id int foreign key references competition(id),
  joker_id int  foreign key references joker(joker_id),
  user_id int  foreign key references user(id),
  point int
);
```

I want write SQL code for this:

- Write the SQL query, which will list which of the most competing members from each category got the highest score, in which category it competed, and how many questions are correct and how many questions are wrong.

I write this SQL query but failure:

```
SELECT category.id, user.id, count(competition_user.competition.id) AS competitioncount 
FROM user, competition_user, competition, category
WHERE competition.id = competition_user.competition_id AND compettion.category_id = category.id AND user.id = competition.user_id
GROUP BY category.id, user.id 
ORDER BY competitioncount desc
```

Comment: What do you mean by "most competing member"?  Where's the data on right/wrong questions?

Comment: At the first look: **user** is reserved key. You should wrap it into quotes: **[user]**.

Comment: 1) You're using old style joins which is a bad practice, consider using proper modern joins. 2) Consider using table aliases for readability. 3) Please provide sample data and expected results to illustrate what you are trying to accomplish. 4) Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)